# C# Variable not changing after Assignment, Change shows in UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

In my scoreboard UI I have a box that is just an image with Score_Entries inside as children. There are 4 children, one for each player in the game. When the scoreboard starts up I have a function that assigns the text inside the Score_Entries Ui elements. To do this I have an array called Text[] playerNames and my UI elements are dragged into this in the inspector.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Player test in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
{
    playerNames[i].text = test.NickName;
    allscores[i].text = 0.ToString();
    i++;
    Debug.Log("Text inside the array: " + playerNames[i].text);
    Debug.Log("Player Name: " + test.NickName);
}
```

As you can see I have set the text inside my first Text element to equal a name of a player. However, what should happen is in the Debug statements the Player Name line output and the Text inside the array output should Show me the string stored inside `test.NickName`. say test is players name. `playersNames[i].text should == test` currently it shows `playerNames[i] = TEST NAME` which is my default text when creating the UI. However, in the game, the name of the player is shown correctly as test not TEST NAME.

I dont see how this is working can someone help?

Comment: A bit confused about your `i++` in the middle between assigning the array and logging ... you will always try and log the **next** item of your arrays ... not those you just assigned

Comment: I coded the logic first then added the Debug statements to see where it was going wrong. I missed I was using the i in the statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is i++
put i++ after

```
Debug.Log("Text inside the array: " + playerNames[i].text);
Debug.Log("Player Name: " + test.NickName);
i++
```

Comment: Thanks! My next issue is I am using this array in other code but It cannot see the new name that I have changed

Comment: you have to change to foreach (Player test in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
        {
            playerNames[i].text = test[i].NickName;
            allscores[i].text = 0.ToString();
            i++;
            Debug.Log("Text inside the array: " + playerNames[i].text);
            Debug.Log("Player Name: " + test[i].NickName);
        }

Comment: I want to access the array in another script so I am expecting playerNames[0] to be equal to test.NickName however it is TEST NAME. So would I access it by doing playerNames[i].NickName?

Comment: Why does it need to be test[i] compared to just test.text? Does the for each loop not get each text as an object?